# mysql DATEDIFF with NULL value

Tags: mysql

I have to compare 2 separate columns. I am using DATEDIFF(date1, date2) to compare them, however, in some records the date is Null, which returns a null result and messes up the CASE.

Is there a way around this, or a way to predetermine which date is null up front?

```
id | D1        | D2
1  | 2020-11-25| 2020-11-26
2  | Null      | Null
3  | 2020-11-22| 2020-11-28
```

I need the result :

T1: 2,null,7

But now I get the result is:

T1: 2,7

My code:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( (DATEDIFF(D2, D1)+1) SEPARATOR ',') as T1 FROM `Apr`
```

Comment: If date is null what will you do up front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CASE WHEN d1 IS NULL OR d2 IS NULL
                          THEN 'NULL'
                          ELSE DATEDIFF(D2, D1)+1
                          END 
                     SEPARATOR ',') as T1 
FROM `Apr`
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90b48e493aaef5d82d22a49b28030dc8)